# Avoid background color from border color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with a background color of rgba(255,0,0,1), and a border color of rgba(0,255,0,0.2), and a 10px border-radius.
The problem is that the border color have the background color under it.
This is my code:

```css
div{
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
  border: 10px solid rgba(0,255,0,0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
article{
  margin: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
  outline: 10px solid rgba(0,255,0,0.2);
  outline-radius: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<article></article>
```

I need a border like at the outline.
Saddly I can't use outline instead because it doesn't have "outline-radius" property, only "-moz-outline-radius", but it doesn't work on Chrome.

Comment: Do you have to use rgba(0,255,0,0.2); ? why not increase the alpha value to a solid colour?

Comment: Border color under it? What is the problem. I do not understand the problem you are facing.

Comment: If it is not understandable, sorry for my English.

Comment: Do you not want the border to count as part of the width? AHHH you want opacity.... Missed the rgba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `box-shadow`, which sits outside the border:

```css
div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  /*extra styling*/
  margin: 50px;
}

/*Just for demo so you can see the transparency*/
body {
  background: #fff url(http://www.destination360.com/north-america/canada/images/s/canada-cn-tower.jpg) repeat;
}
```

```html
<div>Red half-opacity box-shadow</div>
```

Comment: @HalasiTamás No prob!  `background-clip` also works, check out both solutions to see which one works best for you.

Comment: But if I use that, it doesn't round the corner

Comment: `box-shadow` works with `border-radius` for me, not sure what's up.

Answer (score 3):

Use  `background-clip: content-box;` or `background-clip: padding-box;`

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip)

> The background-clip CSS property specifies whether an element's background, either the color or image, extends underneath its border.

---

```css
div{
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
  border: 10px solid rgba(0,255,0,0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-clip: content-box;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the `background-clip` attribute:

```css
div {
  background-clip: padding-box;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
  border: 10px solid rgba(0,255,0,0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
article {
  background-clip: padding-box;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
  outline: 10px solid rgba(0,255,0,0.2);
  outline-radius: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<article></article>
```

Comment: Totally works! I searched so much, but I didn't find it, thank You!

Answer (score -1):

Try using two div.

```css
div.outer {
  border: 10px solid rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
div.inner {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is possible to do it like this but there are much cleaner ways to achieve the requested result.